# appgyver supersonic add simple image

Tags: angularjs

How do I add a simple svg image to my login page?  I've tried img ng-src and div list card and a simple css class called logo but my image is never shown.  I never get a file not found but I wonder if I'm placing the image in the correct location - any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look in your dist folder, and check where your images are in relation to your html folder.  For me, it was up two folders:

```
<img src="../../icons/myicon.svg" />
```